# Flexbox itemswith not aligned to the left inside my container with column flow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have this container where I want all items to start filling from top to bottom, when the items start to wrap I want them to keep stacking to the left instead of the next row appearing to be floating to the right of the container.

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:300px; display:flex; outline:2px solid blue;flex-direction:column; flex-wrap:wrap;">
    <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; "></div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; "></div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; "></div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; "></div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; "></div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; "></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the alignment for the *cross-axis* by setting `align-content: flex-start` on the outer wrapper.

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:300px; display:flex; outline:2px solid blue;flex-direction:column; flex-wrap:wrap;align-content:flex-start">
    <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; ">1</div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; ">2</div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; ">3</div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; ">4</div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; ">5</div>
 <div style="width:33.33%; height:33.33%; outline:1px solid red; ">6</div>
</div>
```